# SSL handshake failure when running httr library in R, and mutual authentication

Tags: r, ssl, https, libcurl, httr

I'm trying to connect to a company server over https using httr library. I have the client certificate and its private key protected by a password. I'm running the following R command :

```
connect = httr::GET("https://someaddress:22667", config(ssl_verifypeer = 0L,  sslcert = "myCert.crt", sslkey = "mykey10.pem",keypasswd = "qwert", verbose = TRUE, sslversion = 6))
```

But it's failing, with this error :

```
failed to receive handshake, SSL/TLS connection failed
```

When testing with this cURL command :

```
curl -k --cert myCert.crt --key myKey10.pem https://someaddress:22667
```

the connection will be established. As I understand, httr is just a wrapper over cURL (more precisely : libcurl is required). When using the same parameters, it is supposed to establish the connection.

Help please!!! I spent a lot of time to resolve this problem, but unsuccessfully.

Comment: please edit your question and tell us the versions of your OS and R software

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the R curl library changelog there were big modifications recently, particularly for Windows users :

> ...
>
> 3.0
>    - MAJOR CHANGE ON WINDOWS: On Windows 7 / 2008-R2 and up we switch from OpenSSL to native Windows SSL    (secure channel). Therefore curl
>   now uses certificates from the windows certificate manager.    This
>   enables users on corporate/government networks to connect through
>   enterprise proxies and such.    On Windows Vista/2008 and older
>   (including CRAN) we still use OpenSSL to guarantee TLS 1.1/1.2
>   support.
>
> ...
>
> 2.8.1
>    - Windows: switch back to OpenSSL instead of SecureChannel because Windows 2008 (CRAN) does not    support TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 which is
>   required for many servers now.

This can explain the different behaviors between the native cURL and its wrapper in R.
If you're on Windows, then, check which version of curl library you are running, and re-install it manually by choosing another version (2.8.1 or 3.0 or 3.1 where we see big changes in the log) :

```
library(curl)
sessionInfo()
other attached packages:
[1] curl_3.1

R CMD REMOVE curl
wget http://cran.univ-paris1.fr/src/contrib/Archive/curl/curl_2.8.1.tar.gz
R CMD INSTALL curl_2.8.1.tar.gz
```

The curl archives are [here](http://cran.univ-paris1.fr/src/contrib/Archive/curl/)

Please give me a feedback on this answer, I spent time on it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200) other attached packages:
[1] curl_3.1. But I've got the same error yet.

Comment: did you try other curl versions from the archive downloads ( 3.0, 2.8.1 ) ?

Comment: I tried, but can not install. ERROR: compilation failed for package 'curl'. I 'm 
 trying to resolve the problem.

Comment: Thank you for help!!! I will try to run my script from other computer, but for me it works successfully. I installed curl version 2.8.1 from your link. I had a problem with package compilation but updating of RTools and installed 32-bit version solve it. Can I ask you, if i will have a question?

Comment: You can ask of course, but remember to mark good answers as good when they are, or upvote. I understand you spent weeks on your problem and you should welcome the time other people spend for you.