# REDCap connection API

Tags: r, redcap

I'm trying to import forms on **R** from REDCap thanks to the API. I managed to do it some time ago thanks to this program:

```
options(redcap_api_url='redcap_api_url')
rcon <- redcapConnection(token='api_token')

df <- exportRecords(rcon)
```

But since a few days, it doesn't work anymore and I get this error message:

> Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :
> schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_ILLEGAL_MESSAGE (0x80090326) - This error usually occurs when a fatal SSL/TLS alert is received (e.g. handshake failed). More detail may be available in the Windows System event log.

I tried to add this to my program:

```
library(httr)    
set_config(use_proxy(url="10.3.100.207",port=8080))
```

But it didn't work, and now I get this message :

> Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :
> Timeout was reached: [epicene.credim.u-bordeaux.fr] Connection timeout after 10471 ms

I can't figure out how to solve this problem.

Comment: These two questions might be relevant: 1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48825135/ssl-handshake-failure-when-running-httr-library-in-r-and-mutual-authentication?rq=3   and 2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64147821/error-running-weathercan-package-fatal-ssl-tls-alert-e-g-handshake-failed     I can't say how the solutions proposed fit with security best practices or within your organization's information security policies. This looks like it might be a result of something on your system or your network. You may want to get your IT group involved.

Comment: thank you for the answer I will test what has been proposed on the other questions otherwise I will call my IT department.